# How much damage should a beholder take if my character jumps onto it and slams it into the ground?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, falling

I was wondering how to rule something in my friend's campaign.

We were fighting a modified beholder boss as a level 13 druid and a level 12 warlock. The fight was at a large summoning circle at the bottom of a 250-foot hole with a diameter of 15 feet. I, the druid, was at the top of the hole and the warlock was levitating up the hole after getting the beholder's attention.

I proceeded to use the *move earth* cantrip to drop 5 feet of stone on top of the beholder as it was rising up. How much damage should this do?

After a couple rounds, the beholder started to go back down after taking a lot of damage. I noticed this and *polymorph*ed into a T-Rex and jumped in the hole. How much damage should the beholder take on impact if the T-Rex hits it, and slams it into the ground?

We then proceeded to fight the beholder which summoned 3 devils and eventually won.

TLDR: I fought a beholder in a 250-foot shaft and jumped in as a T-Rex and smashed it into the ground. How do you rule that for damage to the beholder?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour], and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Wouldn't this be slightly different than the proposed duplicate since Beholders levitate and was specifically stated to be rising/moving up in the first example?  Seems more like the OP is asking two distinct questions. 1. How much damage if dropping something on a beholder moving up? and 2. How much damage falling on a beholder and smashing it into the ground? #2 is similar to the proposed duplicate, but still, I think, different enough.  #1 is definitely different.

Comment: I agree, I think the OPs question requires a look at the spell Levitate as well, which is different. Perhaps a rewording of the question?

Comment: And polymorph...and potentially the weight of t-rex. It should also be pointed out that the t-rex/character would probably take damage too, if it works.